# Validating passwords in SQL database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, hash, passwords

I need some help, and I've read so many posts on here and everywhere but can't get my code to validate the password. So I need some help.

First, I can read all data such as username and password from database, I've checked if the values is not null by showing the password for example in a messagebox. I get the password that is stored in the database, but I don't understand how I am supposed to validate a RANDOM GENERATED salt + hash.

Here is my code and everything you see in it is what I've tried so far:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", textBoxUserName.Text); //enter the value from the textbox

    connection.Open(); 

    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxUserName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPassword.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter username or password!");
    }

    // read the value in DB based on the input we get from the user
    while (sdr.Read())
    {                      
        getUsernameFromDB = sdr.GetString(0);
        getPasswordFromDB = sdr.GetString(1);   // we can get the password now, so validate the password!!!                     
    }
                
    // hash the input and adding salt to it
    string newHashSaltToCompare = GenerateSaltedHash(textBoxPassword.Text);   

    // comparing the data but nothing happens
    if (getPasswordFromDB == newHashSaltToCompare)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User: {0} logged in!", getUsernameFromDB); 
    }
    else
    {
         // no user is found
    }
                
    sdr.Close();
}

connection.Close();
```

Here are my hashing and salting methods:

```
private byte[] GenerateSalt()
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];

    using (var rng = RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(salt);
    }

    return salt;
}

private string GenerateSaltedHash(string password)
{
    string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(password: password,
        salt: GenerateSalt(),
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));

    return $"{hashed}:{Convert.ToBase64String(GenerateSalt())}";
}
```

What I want is to validate the password in the database with the help from textBoxPassword.text input. But I get no result.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that when you are creating the hash for the value of `textBoxPassword.Text` you are not providing the hashing algorithm with the same salt as when you first generated the stored password hash. If you pass a new salt into the hashing algorithm at every validation, you will never receive a valid hash

You could remedy this by storing the original salt next to the password in your database, then when you want to validate a provided password, you would pass the stored salt into the hashing algorithm. See the following example using argon2id as the hashing algorithm:

This class `HashManager` is responsible for creating/validating password the password hashes.

```cs
public class HashManager
{
    public bool ValidateLogin(byte[] trueHash, byte[] salt, string username, string password)
    {
        return HashPassword(username + password, salt).SequenceEqual(trueHash);
    }


    public CreatedHash CreateAuthenticationHash(string username, string password)
    {
        byte[] salt = CreateSalt();
        byte[] hash = HashPassword(username + password, salt);
        return new CreatedHash(hash, salt);
    }

    private byte[] CreateSalt()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[16];
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetBytes(buffer);
        return buffer;
    }

    private byte[] HashPassword(string input, byte[] salt)
    {
        Argon2id argon2 = new Argon2id(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        argon2.Salt = salt;
        argon2.DegreeOfParallelism = 8; // four cores
        argon2.Iterations = 4;
        argon2.MemorySize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 GB

        return argon2.GetBytes(16);
    }

    public class CreatedHash
    {
        public byte[] Hash { get; set; }
        public byte[] Salt { get; set; }

        public CreatedHash(byte[] hash, byte[] salt)
        {
            Hash = hash;
            Salt = salt;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample of how you might use the provided `HashManager` to Create and Validate your passwords

```cs
//Generate the "true hash" at account creation
CreateUserHash(string username, string password)
{
    //This HashManager class returns a new object CreatedHash with the generated hash and the salt used to do so for convenience
    CreatedHash hash = new HashManager().CreateAuthenticationHash(username, password);

    //Here you would store both the password hash and the salt in your database.
    //The hash and the password hash may even be stored on the same table
    StoreNewUser(CreatedHash);
}

//Use the provided HashManager to validate the password hash

OnLoginButtonClicked()
{
    //get stored values from your database
    byte[] trueHash = GetHashFromDB();
    byte[] salt = GetSaltFromDB();
    

    //Give the Hashing Algorithm the "True Hash" and the salt used to generate the True Hash
    if (new HashManager().ValidateLogin(trueHash, salt, usernameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text))
         LogUserIn();
    else RejectLogin();
}
```

Notice how HashManager.ValidateLogin() takes the same salt used to generate the original hash and then uses that very same salt to generate a hash using the provided username/password, then compares the two sequences for validation. Assuming that I read and understood your provided code correctly, I believe this is the crux of your issue.

Side note: Please do not use SHA as a password hashing algorithm, as it is vulnurable to rainbow table/lookup table. [See this article](https://dusted.codes/sha-256-is-not-a-secure-password-hashing-algorithm). I would recommend the use of [Argon2id](https://argon2.online/), an implementation of Argon2, winner of the Password Hashing Competition

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! So I read the answer that you gave me, and this is what I'm looking for. I will read this closely to learn and see what I did wrong, thank you!